Sci-fi disaster movie that includes travel to different dimension through a portal and "Hard Light Bridge"
I can't remember the name of a sci-fi movie that I've seen years ago. I've seen it at least 5 years ago or more.  In the movie a corporation was involved in exploring another earth or involved in travelling to different times of the earth by using a portal (like "Ground Bridge" in Transformers Prime). They traveled on a bridge-like structure made of light (like "Hard Light Bridge" in Portal 2, but wider). Later, some of the team members accidentally made change in the traveled world and in result, their own world gets spoiled.

Sounds like A Sound of Thunder from 2005 with Edward Burns and Ben Kingsley. From IMDb:

[In] 2055, Charles Hatton has made a fortune by founding 'Time safari', which offers rich 'big game hunters' short time travels to kill off dinosaurs just before their natural death... They soon face 'time waves', each worsening the effects in 2055 of evolutionary distortions, lower lifeforms first.

You can see the shiny bridge they use for time travel in the trailer around 0:43 (there's also a still below). If I recall correctly, they must never veer off from it - but they do, of course, and their actions in the prehistoric past start altering the present. The entire movie is currently available on Youtube.


Similar answer here, though the question's kind of different: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9545/sci-fi-movie-present-changes-due-to-killing-a-butterfly-in-pre-history
